# Get a value from a class in script

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

how can I call action and import a value in javascript?
I have a c# program and need to get a string value in part of javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
$('#Country').change(function () { var selectedCountry = 
$("#Country").val();
var regionsSelect =  --->i need get a value by call from a class here <------
```

Thanks.

Comment: Programms and Javascripts do not interact, unless the "Programm" is a WebBrowser - and those should just run JS, without thinking about it. Important details are missing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for calling a method in your controller (if your using e.g. asp.net / core).

For example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string selectedCountry)
    {
        var region = getRegion(selectedCountry);
        return Json(region);
    }
```

```
$(function () {
            $('#Country').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ControllerName/AjaxMethod",
                    data: { "selectedCountry": $("#Country").val() },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var regionSelected = response.###
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        // console.log(reponse)
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        // console.log(reponse)
                   }
                });
            });
        });
```

Hopefully, a solution for you. :)